# MongoDB, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: java, mongodb

Program is failing on line 1

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
```

With

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ACKNOWLEDGED
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions$Builder.<init>(MongoClientOptions.java:54)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:126)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:115)
```

While mongo is,

```
Tue Nov 27 15:40:13 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

What am i doing wrong please?

Comment: could you provide versions of server, driver you are using?

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you have multiple versions of the mongo-java-driver jar in your classpath.  Try running with -verbose:class to see where the WriteConcern class is being loaded from.

Comment: removing the multiple versions solved my problem.. thanks :)

Comment: Where does this need to run? I am facing the same issue, would really appreciate if someone could help me out. I am new to Scala.

Comment: I was running `spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.0 --jars mongo-hadoop-spark-2.0.2.jar,mongo-java-driver-3.2.2.jar` earlier but running `spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.0` instead worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

use this line.

Mongo mongo= new Mongo("localhost", 27017);

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I realized that I have two java libraries for reading Mongo DB. When I removed one of them (com.mongodb-x-x.jar), the error disappeared.